# Emberjs New routing and query string or custom route matcher

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to migrate my app to the new emberjs routing API.

With old router I had some workarounds to provide similar URI for objects saved by ID and for new objects which described by set of params. This were done for ability of exchange links to objects between users without permanently saving it. This is two simplified valid routes from my app:

```
/objects/12                   // fetch object by id (/objects/:object_id)
/objects/<serialized params>  // build new object from params (/objects/:params)
```

Both of this routes are similar to router because they all have dynamic parts and static parts are equal. So I wrote custom `RouteMatcher` to pickup right route. Lack of query string parsing forced me to do this hack as quick and semilegal solution, also there is [ancient ticket](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1487) about this feature on github.

With the new router matching has been extracted to separate package (route-recognizer) so I cannot do the trick (or it will be full of hacks and injections).

As I can see I have to choose from these options:

- Totally rewrite my URIs and separate all intersecting routes
- Rewrite URIs but try to implement query string parser for the new Ember.Router
- Put all logic into one route and reimplement only serialize/deserialize methods (something dirty)

Second solution seems to be more clean.

What will be the best non complicated decision? Should I try to find another way?

Comment: Overriding route's model method doesn't do the trick?

Comment: This is option #3. Definitely it will do but rest part of routes is slightly different for saved and new objects, so logic will be messed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current router does not support query-string parameters.

We are tracking this bug at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1773. You may want to follow it.

In the meantime, your best bet is probably to use a dynamic segment and manually serialize (with the `serialize` hook) and deserialize (with the `model` hook).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll try to use this solution. It seems I need simplify logic of all my routes. Also it is possible to place static routes on the same level as dynamic?

Comment: You can put static and dynamic routes at the same level. If both a static and dynamic route matches, the static route wins. This is so that `/posts/new` wins over `/posts/:post_id`.

Comment: Ok. Going to continue investigations.

Comment: I have gotten good results by matching the route {path: 'objects/*everythingAfter'}... then you get params.everythingAfter as something like "hello/world/this/is/awesome" which you can tokenise yourself.